# How can we format the `Track Change` text color/font in Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

In `Track Change` mode we have the display text marked as changed text in red color and underline which I wanna change. How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change color settings for Change Tracking in Word:

1. Open the **Review** tab
2. Expand the **Track Changes** option
3. Select **Change Tracking Options...**

[image]

You can select different colors for every tracked change type

[image]